# Get encrypted NSString from another NSString and key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encryption

How can I generate an encrypted string with a string and a key? Something like...

```
NSString *key = @"password";
NSString *stringToBeEncrypted = @"This is important";
NSString *result = [Encryptor encryptedStringForKey:key string:stringToBeEncrypted];
```

Comment: What class is that Encryptor?

Comment: There are more ways to encrypt stuff than there are questions on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ ;-) And at least a dozen of them are viable to use these days. You'll have to be far more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many types of encoding,

Here one sample,

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *key = @"my password";
NSString *secret = @"text to encrypt";
NSData *plain = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *cipher = [plain AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
plain = [cipher AES256DecryptWithKey:key];
[pool drain];


- (NSData*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
}

- (NSString*) decryptData:(NSData*)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[ciphertext AES256DecryptWithKey:key]
                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the frequently used is AES256Encryption, which is implemented as:

```
NSString *stringToBeEncrypted = @"This is important";
NSString *key = @"password"; 

NSLog( @"Original String: %@", stringToBeEncrypted );

NSString *encryptedString = [stringToBeEncrypted AES256EncryptWithKey:key];

NSLog( @"Encrypted String: %@", encryptedString );

NSLog( @"Decrypted String: %@", [encryptedString AES256DecryptWithKey:key] );
```